# NGINX remove all extension types in uri

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, rewrite

How would I remove all extension types in the uri through nginx config. 
I have looked around for solutions and only found solutions for specific file types. For example some configurations would rewrite all html files. abc.com/hello/world.html to abc.com/hello/world. Others do that with php. I am trying to create a configuration to take the uri and remove the extension, redirect index to the /, and remove any extra back slash at the end of the uri.

Here are some examples:

/hello/world.php -> /hello/world (and entering /hello/world would render /hello/world.php, html, asp, txt in that order but without the extension in the url bar)

/hello/index.php -> /hello

/hello/ -> /hello

/hello/world.html -> /hello/world

etc.